# 機械学習の可視化のグラフの見方

Tags: 機械学習

ちらほら見かける機械学習の結果を可視化したグラフで横軸エポック数，縦軸MSE？になっているものをよく見かけます．
この二つの線の意味としてはトレーニングデータをトレーニングデータで学習したものでテストした場合のMSEと，テストデータをトレーニングデータで学習したものでテストした場合のMSEという見方であっていますか？

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> トレーニングデータをトレーニングデータで学習したものでテスト

基本的にはその認識であっていますが、学習後に改めてトレーニングデータを使ってテストしなおすわけではないので注意してください。
学習中は常に誤差を計算しています。
誤差を減らすようにモデルを修正するのが学習だからです。
青線は、エポック毎の誤差（左グラフ：loss）や正答率（右グラフ：accuracy）を表しています。

> テストデータをトレーニングデータで学習したものでテストした

こちらの認識は問題ないと思います。
橙線は、エポック毎にテストデータでテストした時の誤差や正答率を表しています。

誤差の計算方法は平均二乗和誤差だけではないのでこちらも注意してください。
学習のアルゴリズムやモデルの目的によって誤差の計算方法は異なります。
例えばニューラルネットワークの分類問題では交差エントロピー誤差がよく利用されます。
このグラフからではどの計算方法を用いたかはわかりません。